# Unrecognized option "resources" under "twig.form"

Tags: symfony, twig

I didn't touch my project since a week and today I have this error when I want to go on my website

Unrecognized option "resources" under "twig.form"

I don't know why.. This was working very fine before...

Here is my config.yml :

```
twig:
debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
globals:
    breadcrumb_trail: "@apy_breadcrumb_trail"
form:
    resources:
      - 'AppBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'
```

If you have any idea.. :)

Comment: Is that really how your file looks like? Because in YAML text indent does matter.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 7):

If you are on SF3 or higher, check that the yaml definition hasn't changed to specify a form template: the current one (3.0.*) should be like this:

```
twig:
    form_themes:
        - 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig'
```

[source](https://symfony.com/doc/master/book/forms.html#twig)